# Why is the first bar so big in my R histogram?

Tags: r, histogram, distribution

I'm playing around with R. I try to visualize the distribution of 1000 dice throws with the following R script:

```
cases <- 1000

min <- 1
max <- 6

x <- as.integer(runif(cases,min,max+1))
mx <- mean(x)
sd <- sd(x)

hist(
  x,
  xlim=c(min - abs(mx/2),max + abs(mx/2)),
  main=paste(cases,"Samples"),
  freq = FALSE,
  breaks=seq(min,max,1)
)

curve(dnorm(x, mx, sd), add = TRUE, col="blue", lwd = 2)
abline(v = mx, col = "red", lwd = 2)

legend("bottomleft", 
       legend=c(paste('Mean (', mx, ')')), 
       col=c('red'), lwd=2, lty=c(1))
```

The script produces the following histogram:
[image: histogram]

Can someone explain to me why the first bar is so big? I've checked the data and it looks fine. How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Also compare `right = TRUE` and `right = FALSE`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Histograms aren't good for discrete data, they're designed for continuous data.  Your data looks something like this:

```
> table(x)
x
  1   2   3   4   5   6 
174 138 162 178 196 152
```

i.e. roughly equal numbers of each value.  But when you put that in a histogram, you chose breakpoints at 1:6.  The first bar has 174 entries on its left limit, and 138 on its right limit, so it displays 312.

You could get a better looking histogram by specifying breaks at the half integers, i.e. `breaks = 0:6 + 0.5`, but it still doesn't make sense to be using a histogram for data like this.   Simply running `plot(table(x))` or `barplot(table(x))` gives a more accurate depiction of the data.

Answer (score 2):

You have incorrect `breaks` and because of this, the first bar is counting 1 and 2's in the roll.

```
hist(
  x,
  xlim=c(0,6),
  main=paste(cases,"Samples"),
  freq = FALSE,
  breaks=seq(0,6,1)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

m0nhawk gets to part of the problem. Another issue might be your use of `as.integer`, which always rounds down (and therefore skews toward `1`).

```
as.integer(1.7)
# 1

round(1.7)
# 2
```

Lastly, I'm not sure why one would fit a gaussian to a uniform distribution. Generating the numbers from `rnorm`, rather than `runif`, would make more sense.